# Active Menu Color Item inwordpress menu sample structure

Tags: css, menu

My menu is like this

```
<div class="header-menu1">

    <div class="menu1a">
        <nav role="navigation" class="site-nav">

            <ul class="main-nav" id="menu-main">
                <li class="menu-item abc1" id="def1"><a>Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item abc2" id="def2"><a>About Us</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item abcd1" id="defg1"><a>Corporate Overview</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item abcd2" id="defg2"><a>Mission, Vision &amp; Core Values</a>    
</li>
                    <li class="menu-item abcd3" id="defg3"><a>Management</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item abc3" id="def3"><a>Services</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item abc4" id="def4"><a>Know Hub</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item abcd4" id="defg4"><a>Articles</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item abcd5" id="defg5"><a>Outsourcing Glossary</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item abcd6" id="defg6"><a>Events</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item abcd7" id="defg7"><a>Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item abc5" id="def5"><a>Clients</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item abc6" id="def6"><a>Reviews</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item abc7" id="def7"><a>Get Started</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item abc8" id="def8"><a>Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to identify the active menu i.e. "main-nav" class's

by #f00 color, viz be it a submenu activeness or main-menu activeness.
I am a Graphic Designer and I want A quick Solution for the above Problem.

Comment: I think is already answered here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086375/how-to-give-a-different-color-to-the-current-selected-list-item-than-other-items

Comment: Is this you are looking? http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/4LB8c/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UL LI.menu-item a:active {
    color:#f00;
}
```

EDIT:

:active isn't what you're after.

Wordpress appends a class to the current menu item. You can just use that:

```
UL LI.current-menu-item a {
    color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: What other thing I have to specify or change because above code is not working.

Comment: Where are you putting this ?

Comment: I mean where in your structure. Have you pasted it into a script block, a style block an external style sheet, etc??

Comment: I am working in Wordpress and i have pasted the code in main style sheet where i was having the other code for css for menu.

Comment: I thin you've misunderstood what :active does. I think instead you want wordpress to append an "active" class to the active link which would then be coloured differently. The :active pseudo selector selects the link when it's actually being clicked. It won't remain in an active state beyond that.

Comment: I want the color to remain in an active state beyond that in Wordpress permanently till the page is active. If you could please help me out!

Comment: Yes, as I said, that's not what :active is for. See my updated response.

Comment: So can :visited help in this issue?

Comment: No. That'll color any link they've previously visited! See my updated response which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Above code is working alright, But how can I work with submenu's item clicked means the color should remain same permanently for sub menu also.

Comment: Select the submenu items UL LI UL.sub-menu LI {} and define a colour.

Comment: What I now want is that change the color of the menu item permanently on selection of the current sub-menu item of that menu only.

Comment: That's a separate question. This isn't a "get you to your ultimate goal" site. Specific answers are given to specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav.site-nav li a:active
{
  color:#your color;
}
```

Comment: What other thing I have to specify or change because above code is not working.

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/ptSt4/. when you press any link, you can see it will change it to pink color(only on the clicking time).