# Highlight active menu item with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have a topnav menu that works fine, I just want to keep the underline that appears on the hover event to stay there if that menu item is active. I have tried many solutions I found on the forum, but somehow none did not work. Any help is appreciated.

and here are the `htm`l and `css` snippets:

```css
 body {
   margin: auto;
 }

 .topnavbar {
   background-color: rgba(20, 180, 255, 1);
   /*rgba(0,255,150,0.6); #3EDC99*/
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
 }

 .nav {
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 }

 html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 *,
 *:before,
 *:after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
 }

 body {
   background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1)/*#3498db; */
 }

 .nav {
   width: 550px;
   margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
 }


 /* Navigation */

 .nav {
   font-family: Verdana, Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
 }

 .nav-items {
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
 }


 /* color of menu links
 span {
  
  color:yellow;
 }
 */

 .nav-item {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 25px;
 }

 .nav-item:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
 }

 .nav-link,
 .nav-link:link,
 .nav-link:visited,
 .nav-link:active,
 .submenu-link,
 .submenu-link:link,
 .submenu-link:visited,
 .submenu-link:active {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 14px;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: none;
   outline: none;
   color: blue;
 }

 .nav-link::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 3px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
   transform: translate(0, 10px);
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
 }

 .nav-link:hover::before,
 .nav-link:hover::before {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
   transform: translate(0, 5px);
 }

 .dropdown {
   position: relative;
 }

 .dropdown .nav-link {
   padding-right: 15px;
   height: 17px;
   line-height: 17px;
 }

 .dropdown .nav-link::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 6px;
   right: 0;
   border: 5px solid transparent;
   border-top-color: blue;
   /*small triangle showing drop down menu*/
 }

 .submenu {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 100;
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: -100px;
   background: blue;
   border-radius: 3px;
   line-height: 1.46667;
   margin-top: -5px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(.85);
   transform: translate(0, 0)scale(.85);
   transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

 .submenu::after,
 .submenu::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -10px;
   border: 10px solid transparent;
   height: 0;
 }

 .submenu::after {
   border-bottom-color: blue;
 }

 .submenu::before {
   margin-left: -13px;
   border: 13px solid transparent;
   border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
   filter: blur(1px);
 }

 .submenu-items {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 10px 0;
 }

 .submenu-item {
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
 }

 .submenu-link,
 .submenu-link:link,
 .submenu-link:visited,
 .submenu-link:active {
   color: #3498db;
   padding: 10px 20px;
 }

 .submenu-link:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
 }

 .submenu-seperator {
   height: 0;
   margin: 12px 10px;
   border-top: 1px solid #eee;
 }

 .show-submenu .submenu {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: translate(0, 25px) scale(1);
   transform: translate(0, 25px) scale(1);
   pointer-events: auto;
 }

 .submenu-link {
   color: red;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/_topnavbar.css' %}">

<!--Top Navigation-->
<nav role="navigation" class="nav" id="topnav">
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Media</span></a>
      <nav class="submenu">
        <ul class="submenu-items">
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #1</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #2</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Search</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Report</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>More</span></a>
      <nav class="submenu">
        <ul class="submenu-items">
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item">
            <hr class="submenu-seperator" />
          </li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/_topnavbar.js' %}"></script>
```

I use `js` to open the drop down menu items, but I don't think it was necessary to make the post more extended than it is now.

Comment: Do you mean using the `:active` selector?

Comment: yes. I mean when you click on the menu item, I want it to  be shown underlined

Answer (score 1):

For as far as I'm concerned, what you are trying to achieve is possible with JS or adding a class to the element. But since you want only CSS, I don't think that's possible.

For if you changed your mind, this is how to do it with adding a class: [How to give a different color to the current selected list item than other items in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086375/how-to-give-a-different-color-to-the-current-selected-list-item-than-other-items)

For JavaScript/jQuery, I guess you could just add this:

```
<script>
  $('.nav-items li a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.nav-items li a').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

EDIT: This is more like what you need:

```
<script>
  var page = window.location.pathname;
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassname("nav-link");
  if (page == "/index/"){
    elements[0].style.textDecoration="underline";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can you modify the code to work with the elements that I have in my html code? and do we need to add anything to the css code or removed from it?

Comment: @Ibo Yes, u should add a style for active class, like text-decoration underline. By the way, i updated my answer :P

Comment: I think the problem is the same thing as when using a css trick: the whole page is refreshed due to a `request` and `.active` class is removed? I am using this in a Django app so things may work a bit differently in other frameworks. A few days ago I deployed a test version here: http://azeribocorp.pythonanywhere.com/index/ you may want to insert the codes you believe and make the clicked menu item red to see if it works or I am missing sth here

Comment: @Ibo ah i get what u mean. Then my answer indeed won't do any good. U could also obtain the current page via javascript, like in  your case índex.html, and give the 'home' nav-item the desired style. Should i edit my answer to that?

Comment: but in that case I have to put this script in every page, right? and it will be the same thing ovokuro suggested and eventually it will not be dynamic and hard to maintain. I realized this is actually a more difficult problem that it looks. There are pretty much big discussion in the forum about this kind of problems and I am still reading to see what is the best resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class e.g. `.is-active`. On the home page you can add this class to the home link in your navigation, like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link is-active"><span>Home</span></a>
</li>
```

In your CSS you style the `is-active` class the same way as the `:hover`.

On each new page of your site, in the HTML, change the location of the `.is-active` class to the appropriate page. If your website is much bigger or more complicated, you can do this programmatically instead.

Basic example:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

.topnavbar {
  background-color: rgba(20, 180, 255, 1);
  /*rgba(0,255,150,0.6); #3EDC99*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}

.nav {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1)/*#3498db; */
}

.nav {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Navigation */

.nav {
  font-family: Verdana, Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-items {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* color of menu links
 span {
  
  color:yellow;
 }
 */

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-link,
.nav-link:link,
.nav-link:visited,
.nav-link:active,
.submenu-link,
.submenu-link:link,
.submenu-link:visited,
.submenu-link:active {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: blue;
}

.nav-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-link:hover::before,
.nav-link:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown .nav-link {
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 17px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.dropdown .nav-link::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: blue;
  /*small triangle showing drop down menu*/
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.46667;
  margin-top: -5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(.85);
  transform: translate(0, 0)scale(.85);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.submenu::after,
.submenu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
}

.submenu::after {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}

.submenu::before {
  margin-left: -13px;
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.submenu-items {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.submenu-item {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.submenu-link,
.submenu-link:link,
.submenu-link:visited,
.submenu-link:active {
  color: #3498db;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.submenu-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.submenu-seperator {
  height: 0;
  margin: 12px 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

.show-submenu .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 25px) scale(1);
  transform: translate(0, 25px) scale(1);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.submenu-link {
  color: red;
}

.nav-link.is-active::before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/_topnavbar.css' %}">

<!--Top Navigation-->
<nav role="navigation" class="nav" id="topnav">
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link is-active"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Media</span></a>
      <nav class="submenu">
        <ul class="submenu-items">
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #1</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #2</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Search</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Report</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>More</span></a>
      <nav class="submenu">
        <ul class="submenu-items">
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item">
            <hr class="submenu-seperator" />
          </li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/_topnavbar.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I can see that it is working fine here, but I made the same changes in my css code, but it is not working on my side. What could be the reason? Is not it because when I clicking, the link calls for a page through request functions and the menu is refreshed?

Comment: @ibo, Ok, in that case the answer from klassjan loosman is more appropriate. I'll update my answer...

Comment: I tested that, I was right. If the menu does not load a page, it will show with underline, otherwise, once the page is rendered, menu goes back to its normal look

Comment: @Ibo, yes `:focus` will be removed once the page updates. I've updated my answer with a method to keep the underline on page refresh.

Comment: I don't get this part: On each new page of your site, in the HTML, change the location of the .is-active class to the appropriate page.

Comment: @Ibo - On the Media page, move the `.is-active` class to the media link. That way the underline will only affect the 'Media' menu item. The `.is-active` class should only be on one `.nav-link` at at time.

Comment: sorry to be slow here, when you say media, do you mean the media which is an item in the menu I have posted? when you say: "move the .is-active class to the media link" how am I supposed to do that? with js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155576/discussion-between-ovokuro-and-ibo).